# What is static fluid-structure interaction?

Tags: fluid-statics

I have came up across the term "static fluid-structure interaction" and I was thinking about it. Static fluid alone means a fluid that is static, or stationary (not moving). But how is it possible for this fluid to interact with a solid and still be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the weight of the water in the lake exerts pressure on the dam, the water is static, the dam is a structure and they interact.